# wait for the data to be obtained to move forward

Tags: angular, angularfire2

I am presenting inconveniences since from my component I only get undefined data. I have a service that retrieves data from firebase, but if I clean the code I realize that the data has not been loaded, it goes to the component and then it returns to the service but it compose and I am left with the undefined parameter

```
@Injectable()
export class ConfigService {
    settings: any;

    constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) {
        this.afs.collection('config/visual').valueChanges().subscribe(configData => {
            this.currentYear = configData.year;
        });
    }
}
```

and from my `config.component.ts` I want to call my service to get the parameter, but it is always undefined unless in my config.service add a timeout

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-control-facturas',
    templateUrl: './control-facturas.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./control-facturas.component.scss'],
})
export class ControlFacturasComponent implements OnInit {
    currentYear: any;

    constructor(private configService: ConfigService) {
        this.currentYear = this.configService.currentYear;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use your service to return the `observable`, and then subscribe it in your component.

In your service, have a method that returns an observable, which contains the data type that you need:

```
@Injectable()
export class ConfigService {
    settings: any;

    constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) {
    }

    getCurrentYear() {
        return this.afs.collection('config/visual').valueChanges()
            .map(configData => configData.year);
    }
}
```

And now in your component, you can simply subscribe it:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-control-facturas',
    templateUrl: './control-facturas.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./control-facturas.component.scss'],
})
export class ControlFacturasComponent implements OnInit {
    currentYear: any;

    constructor(private configService: ConfigService) {
        this.configService.getCurrentYear()
            .subscribe(year => {
                this.currentYear = year;
            })
    }
}
```

You should not subscribe your data in your service, but in component. Reason being because `Observable`s are asynchornous, and that explains you get undefined in your component: The data is not emitted yet when the class is initiated (in constructor phase). It works if you put a `setTimeout`, because hopefully (or luckily) by then, the data has been resolved and you got the data.

Comment: because the .map is used in getCurrentYear () ?

Comment: @LuisRuizFigueroa what do you mean by because? no, the `.map()` simply just transform the object into the format you want. Since you are only interested in the `year` property, you can just pluck it out

Comment: if I call it from another service, should it work?, I'm trying to call currentYear () from another service but the last thing it processes is the subscription

Comment: @LuisRuizFigueroa yes it will work. You have to inject `ConfigService` to that service.

Comment: I just tried, but the subscription is solved at the end of the test https://pastebin.com/LPszTiWP

Comment: @LuisRuizFigueroa no, you still subscribe in your service. I have said that in my answer that do not subscribe in the service, but subscribe in the component.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164615/discussion-between-luis-ruiz-figueroa-and-cozyazure).

Answer (score 0):

You just need to return observable from service on value change and subscribe those changes in component.

```
 getCollection(){
  return this.afs.collection('config/visual').valueChanges();)}

// Component
 this.configService.getCollection().subscribe(res=>{

 this.currentYear = res.currentYear;
})
```

Please make the changes accordingly.